# Android: Determine if notifications are turned off by the user

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications

I'm using Notifications (`NotificationManager.notify()`) in my Countdown Timer app to sound an alarm in case the user is involved in a different app at the time it goes off.

It works really well, unless the user turns off notification (from the quick settings in JellyBeans+).

I want to check in code if the notification option is turned off, so I can choose a different alarm method.

Surprisingly, I found no information on the subject, and diving into Android code I see no such option in `NotificationManager`, and it fails silently.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: FYI, that setting turns off Toasts as well. [Rant](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/app-builder/android-jelly-bean-ate-my-toast/2349)

Comment: @ErikB Ouch, another feature we can't trust. Well, at least for toast there's an alternative - you can display a home made view instead. Good opportunity for a small open source project to create an alternative.

Comment: @Sam asking this 4 years ago I've searched everywhere before posting a question. I guess that the other question was not popular yet. Thanks for the pointer - I'm glad to learn that there's a new solution for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My post is old, but at last! In the support library for API 19+ there is an API for that now

> [NotificationManagerCompat.areNotificationsEnabled()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/app/NotificationManagerCompat#areNotificationsEnabled())